# Tensorflow imprecise timeouts

Tags: tensorflow

I've been testing out the the timeout functionality for sess.runs (applied to a convolutional neural network), and it seems like the timeouts aren't very precise.

For example, if I set the timeout to be 800 ms, there might be a 1-2 second delay before the timeout exception is triggered. This sort of leads me to believe that cancellation notifications aren't caught between computational nodes. (Which according to the timeline are .2-.5 s each)

So

1) Is there a way to make the timeouts more precise?

2) Are Tensorflow cancellation notifications caught between node computations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cancellation and timeout mechanism in TensorFlow was only designed to cancel a small number of **blocking** operations, in particular: [dequeuing](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/io_ops/queues#QueueBase.dequeue) from an empty queue, [enqueuing](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/io_ops/queues#QueueBase.enqueue) to a full queue, and [reading](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/io_ops/readers#ReaderBase.read) from a file.

If you run a graph containing **non-blocking** operations, such as [`tf.matmul()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/math_ops/matrix_math_functions#matmul) and [`tf.nn.conv2d()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/nn/convolution#conv2d), and the timeout expires, TensorFlow will typically wait until these operations have completed before returning with a "deadline exceeded" error.

Why is this the case? We added cancellation because users started to build pipelines of blocking operations into their graphs (e.g. for [reading data](https://www.tensorflow.org/how_tos/reading_data/)) and some form of cancellation was needed to shut down these pipelines cleanly. Timeouts also help to debug deadlocks that can unfortunately occur in these pipelines. By contrast, TensorFlow is designed to dispatch non-blocking operations as efficiently as possible: for example, when running on a GPU, TensorFlow will asynchronously enqueue multiple operations on the GPU compute stream without blocking on their completion. Although it would technically be possible to check for cancellation between the execution of each operation, this would add latency to operation dispatch, and reduce overall performance in the common case.

However, if timeouts/cancellation for non-blocking operations would be useful for your use case, please feel free to open a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues) as a feature request!

Comment: Cool, it's good to know that only a small number of blocking operations are cancellable.

Comment: I see `WaitForNotificationWithTimeout` and `WaitForNotification` sprinkled in places that seem to be cancellable.  Would adding `WaitForNotificationWithTimeout` to non-blocking operations make them cancellable as well?

I'm trying to get a sense of what is required to disable / enable cancellation between graph ops so that I can try making the modification. I'll probably open a github feature request to address it as well.

Comment: There are probably some cases that could be solved that way, but the general problem is not quite that simple, because non-blocking operations almost never wait explicitly for a notification, and a `run()` call must wait until any in-progress work has completed before returning (to avoid dangling pointers). A lot of the implicit blocking is in Eigen (where parallel work is sharded across multiple threads) or the GPU device (where the runtime synchronizes with the GPU stream to ensure that all asynchronous work has completed). Each of these is possible to fix, but might require large changes...

Comment: I see... would a viable option be to check the `cancellation_manager_'s` `IsCancelled` property in the executor class (maybe in `NodeDone` or `ScheduleReady`), and if so, return? I'm currently trying that but it seems that some threads' `cancellation_manager_` is not being cancelled (leading to a deadlock). Just wondering if there are any fatal flaws in this idea...

Comment: Checking `cancellation_manager_->IsCancelled()` in the executor might help to exit early, but it wouldn't help with cancelling work issued on the GPU stream. AIUI, there should be one cancellation manager per step, so I'm not sure what you mean about other threads. That code is quite complicated, so there may be multiple places that need to be changed (and some benchmarking would be needed to ensure that it doesn't cause performance regressions for fine-grained workloads).

Comment: Ah yeah I see what you mean about the cancellation manager per step, I got a little confused by the code. Not sure what to do about cancellation on the GPU... I think I'll focus on the CPU first to see if I can just get that working (for our project, we might not need to use the GPU). I think I have a sense of what's required for catching cancellations between ops now for the CPU. Thanks a ton for your time and help!

Comment: I just want to clarify one more thing -- from looking at the code the timeouts seems to apply to operations rather than the session run. For example, if I set the timeout to 1s, then a chain of N dequeues that each take .999s would make the whole session run take .999N seconds. So the timeout really applies to the operations of the graph (and only a select few), and it doesn't limit the time of the sess.run call. Does this sound right or am I missing something?