# What does the "rest_api_timeout_in_ms"-option actually control?

Tags: tensorflow-serving

I have a (python) app that sends inference requests to TFServing. I want to these requests to timeout after 2 seconds. Naively, i would expect --rest_api_timeout_in_ms would be my friend here. However, after setting it, i get a strange behaviour - i receive a timeout (504 response), but only *after it finished processing* instead of after 2 seconds.

That is - if i sent a request that takes 5 seconds *without* specifying the timeout, i get a 200 after 5 seconds.
If i set the timeout to eg. 2 seconds, the request will still process for 5 seconds and then i receive a 504.

Am i fundamentally misunderstanding what this parameter does?

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41555612/tensorflow-imprecise-timeouts/41557248#41557248
Also, if possible provide the snnippet where you are using --rest_api_timeout_in_ms

Comment: docker run -p 8501:8501 -it -v /opt/tf_models/my_model/my_model:/models/my_model -e TF_CPP_MIN_VLOG_LEVEL=1 -e MODEL_NAME=my_model tensorflow/serving --rest_api_timeout_in_ms=1000
From what i gather from that response - timeouts are not applicable once the "actual" processing in TFS has started?